# trying to understand gradle file

Tags: groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to change a `build.gradle` file of an existing project that was handed to me. I'm new to gradle and groovy so I am trying to decode what it is doing exactly. The documentation of gradle and groovy is not helping me much. Here is an example:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'
apply plugin: "net.saliman.cobertura"
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

// lots of code here....

task('devRun') {
    doLast {    
        bootRun {
            systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "local, dev"
            if (System.getenv('DEBUG') == 'true') {
                jvmArgs '-Xdebug',
                        '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5081'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To me it kinda looks like several nested closure definitions, meaning `task` is the outer closure, `doLast` is the inner closure, `bootRun` is further inner closure. But aren't groovy closures of the form `{statement...}` not `label {statement...}`. Also aren't all these (task, doLast, bootRun) keywords or predefined tasks of other plugins? If that is the case what does it actually mean to say `doLast {statement...}` or `bootRun {statement...}`? is this like overriding predefined `doLast`? and same for `bootRun`. I'm not finding any examples in the documentation that look quite like this code snippet. Could somebody please explain what groovy syntax rules apply here?

Comment: `x {}` is short for `x({})` or even`x() {}`.  Parens are (mostly optionnal) and a final Closure argument is allowed to recide outside of the parens.

Comment: ok I think I get it. to make sure I understand, in the case of `task` I'm interpreting that the predefined `task` method is called with arguments 'devRun' and the 2nd argument is the closure that is defined inline and that calls `doLast`? Thanks